# Is there a way to use perf tracepoints without running as root?

Tags: linux, perf

#### Summary:

I want to be able to profile the event `sched:sched_stat_sleep` without running as root.  Is this possible?

#### Details:

When I run the command: `sudo perf stat -e sched:sched_stat_sleep sleep 1` I get output that looks correct:

```
Performance counter stats for 'sleep 1':

   1,001,729,231      sched:sched_stat_sleep                                      

   1.002880455 seconds time elapsed
```

But when I run without `sudo` I get the error

```
invalid or unsupported event: 'sched:sched_stat_sleep'
Run 'perf list' for a list of valid events

 usage: perf stat [<options>] [<command>]

    -e, --event <event>   event selector. use 'perf list' to list available events
```

And when I run `perf list` without `sudo` part of the output is:

```
[ Tracepoints not available: Permission denied ]
```

I found [anther question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14227/do-i-need-root-admin-permissions-to-run-userspace-perf-tool-perf-events-ar) which suggests setting `kernel.perf_event_paranoid` to `-1`.  I tried doing this but it doesn't appear to make a difference.  I did not reboot after making the change (is that necessary?).  Viewing the setting seems to indicate that it's set to -1 now.

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid 
-1
```

I'm running Arch Linux with Linux kernel version `3.19.2-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT`

Comment: The solution to this problem is that the regular user needs permission to debugfs.  I'll post an answer in a few days if no one else does.

Comment: pls do post answer